# Deleting records in one file using SQL with multiple file joins

Tags: sql, join, sql-delete

I run the following query to confirm that the results of this query are the records I would like to delete from YCSEFMST.

```
select * from libr/yacctmst
         join libr/ycsefmst on ctctcd = efctcd
         join libr/ycsiamst on upper(efmail) = upper(iaaddr)
where ctbkng = 'MDE'
```

The fields ctctcd and ctbkng are from file yacctmst.
The field efctcd is from ycsefmst.
The field iaaddr is from ycsiamst.

How do I now use this statement to delete the records from file YCSEFMST?

I have tried the following statement and it deletes every record in YCSEFMST.

```
delete libr/ycsefmst
where exists ( select * from libr/ycsefmst
                        join libr/yacctmst on ctctcd = efctcd
                        join libr/ycsiamst on upper(efmail) = upper(iaaddr)
               where ctbkng = 'MDE' )
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you,
Diana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Delete from libr/ycsefms Where ID IN
select ID from libr/yacctmst
         join libr/ycsefmst on ctctcd = efctcd
         join libr/ycsiamst on upper(efmail) = upper(iaaddr)
where ctbkng = 'MDE'
```

Obviously, you need to replace ID with the column name that you want to use as a unique identifier.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  That worked exactly as I hoped.  What a simple change and I just didn't see it.